# how to return indexes that makes best sum in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I just need to input an array and make the program return the range of index which produces highest sum.

Examples

For A = {5, -6, 7, -5, 10, -1} – the best sum consists of the values in A[2..4] for a total of 7 + -5 + 10 = 12

For A = {1, 2, 4, -6, 4, 2, 1} – the best sum consists of the values in A[0..6] (the entire array) for a total of 8

For A = {-5, 2, -3, 1, -5, 4, -2} – the best sum consists of the value in A[5] for a total of 4

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me return the following values

Here is my code(doesn't seem to run properly)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int the_resource_collection( int arr[], int len){
  int highest, start, end, i, result;
  highest = arr[len-1];// the limits of the highest value
  start = len - 1;
  end =  len - 1;// all the variables in the total indexes
  for( i=0; i<len-2; i++)
  {
    for (a=i; a<len-1; a++)
    {
        result= arr[i]+ arr[a];// try to find the total of the index
        {
            if (result > highest)
            {
                highest = result;
                start = i;
                end = a;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return start;
  return end;
}
int main()
{
  int a[6] = {5, -6, 7, -5, 10, -1};
  int length = 6;
  printf("%d",the_resource_collection(&a[6],length));
}
```

Comment: This call: `printf("%d",the_resource_collection(&a[6],length));}` makes no sense at all, you're passing a pointer to one element past the end of the array? It should just be `a`.

Comment: Am I seeing a double `return` ? You may only `return` one variable per function. Two returns in a row is useless and confusing.

Comment: sorry;; I'm just very new C programming..I just wanted to find a way to make my function return the value of "start" and "end".

Comment: if you want to return value of 2 different variables, you could use a struct or an array of 2 ints

Comment: You may be new to C, but there also errors in your logical thinking which are not related to C. For example, `result= arr[i]+ arr[a];` will only make a result of two array elements, not of a sequence of elements.

Comment: I wanted to add from arr[i] to arr[a] which I'm not sure how to.my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have some mistakes.

Firstly, in `printf("%d",the_resource_collection(&a[6],length));` you are only passing to the function the sixth element of the array.

Also your `for` loops aren't considering all elements of the array. Finally you also need to save the begining and ending in a `int` array.

Here is how I would do it (I've tested it with the 3 inputs you've provided and the output is as expected!):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * the_resource_collection( int arr[], int len){
    int highest;
    int returnvalue[2];
    int i;
    int a;
    int result;
    highest = arr[len-1];// the limits of the highest value
    returnvalue[0] = len - 1;
    returnvalue[1] = len - 1;// all the variables in the total indexes
    for( i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        result= arr[i];
        for (a=i+1; a<len; a++)
        {
                if (result > highest)
                {
                    highest = result;
                    returnvalue[0] = i;
                    returnvalue[1] = a-1;
                }
                result+=arr[a];
        }
        if (result > highest)
        {
            highest = result;
            returnvalue[0] = i;
            returnvalue[1] = a-1;
        }
        result=0;
    }
    return returnvalue;
}
int main()
{
    int a[7] = {5, -6, 7, -5, 10, -1};
    int length = 7;
    printf("A[%d...%d]\n",the_resource_collection(a,length)[0],the_resource_collection(a,length)[1]);
}
```

If you don't understand what I wrote, or need anymore help, please say so.